# FFmpeg: How to convert horizontal video 16:9 to vertical video 9:16, with blurred background on top and bottom sides

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I know there is a post to do the contrary:
[FFmpeg: How to convert vertical video with black sides, to video 16:9, with blurred background sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789367/ffmpeg-how-to-convert-vertical-video-with-black-sides-to-video-169-with-blur)

but i can't figure out how to do this with ffmpeg

here is the input:

[image]

and here is the expected result (the background video should be zoomed with the same aspect ratio, cropped to 9/16 and blurred) :

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I adapted solution proposed by Mulvya

here is the final result:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -lavfi "[0:v]scale=256/81*iw:256/81*ih,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/40:luma_power=3:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/40:chroma_power=1[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,setsar=1,crop=w=iw*81/256"  output.mp4
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to output it to RTMP stream and not get `av_interleaved_write_frame`?

Answer (score 6):

Adapted from the linked thread:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -lavfi "[0:v]scale=iw:2*trunc(iw*16/18),boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,setsar=1" {-other parameters} output.mp4
```

Comment: Hi thanks i figure out how to do what exactly i wanted to do, thanks to you :-)