# FFmpeg: How to convert horizontal video 16:9 to vertical video 9:16, with Black background on top and bottom sides

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I wanted convert 16:9 video to 9:16 and find this: 
"[FFmpeg: How to convert horizontal video 16:9 to vertical video 9:16, with blurred background on top and bottom sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675923/ffmpeg-how-to-convert-horizontal-video-169-to-vertical-video-916-with-blurre)"

But I want video top and bottom sides black but I couldn't. How can I do this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Remove `,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1` from my answer in that thread.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: ```ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -lavfi "[0:v]scale=iw:2*trunc(iw*16/18)[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,setsar=1" output.mp4``` I used this command but top and bottom sides were not black.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "pad=iw:2*trunc(iw*16/18),setsar=1" -c:a copy output.mp4`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and interested.

Comment: I tried the command you wrote, but this time only the bottom side was black and the top was completely absent. So the video is stuck to the top.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the final command. The video is padded to 9:16 and placed in the centre.

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "pad=iw:2*trunc(iw*16/18):(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1" -c:a copy output.mp4`