# FFmpeg: convert any video to square 1:1 video with blurred side bars

Tags: video, command-line, ffmpeg, windows-scripting

Very similar to this topic:

[FFmpeg: How to convert vertical video with black sides, to video 16:9, with blurred background sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789367/ffmpeg-how-to-convert-vertical-video-with-black-sides-to-video-169-with-blur)

I'm trying to make myself a bat file that will automate my Instagram video creations.
The idea is that I make videos of variable resolutions and variable aspect ratios. I don't want to spend time on each video just to make it fit.

So here's my goal with that bat file:

- Must output a square video
- The original video must keep its original aspect ratio no matter what it is
- The blank spaces filling the voids from the original video and the square aspect ratio must be filled with a squared & blurred version of the original video
- Optionally, let me choose the output resolution (for encoding time saving and because AFAIK Instagram displays only 600px² videos(?))

So far I managed to get results that work only for either vertical or horizontal videos but not both. Or end up with the original video cropped, which I don't want: I frame my subjects as I want and I don't want to frame them forethinking the additional cropping a FFmpeg encoding could do.

This is my script so far:

```sh
echo off
:again

ffmpeg.exe -i "%~1" ^
    -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=600*2:600*2,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[0:v]scale=600:-1[ov];[bg][ov]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,crop=w=600:h=600"  -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset faster -tune fastdecode ^
    -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k ^
    -movflags faststart ^
    "%~p1%~n1_Instagramized.mp4" -y

if NOT ["%errorlevel%"]==["0"] pause
shift
if "%~1" == "" goto:eof
goto:again
```

EDIT:

Thanks to @Gyan I got [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58892567/10705720). I added my input as well:

Since I might reuse that bat file often and might want to change the output resolution, It's not handy to have the resolution hardcoded in six different places.
So I create a variable called `SquareSize` which is called using `%SquareSize%` (instead of the hardcoded resolution) and set at the begining of the file using `set SquareSize=XXX`. So now I can change easily when I need just by opening it and editing the XXX.

```sh
echo off
:again

set SquareSize=600

ffmpeg.exe -i "%~1" ^
    -c:v libx264 -crf 23 ^
    -filter_complex "[0:v]split=2[blur][vid];[blur]scale=%SquareSize%:%SquareSize%:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=%SquareSize%:%SquareSize%,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[vid]scale=%SquareSize%:%SquareSize%:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[ov];[bg][ov]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" ^
    -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset faster -tune fastdecode ^
    -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k ^
    -movflags faststart ^
    "%~p1%~n1_Instagramized.mp4" -y

if NOT ["%errorlevel%"]==["0"] pause
shift
if "%~1" == "" goto:eof
goto:again
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what the filter_complex should be,

`"[0:v]split=2[blur][vid];[blur]scale=L:L:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=L:L,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[vid]scale=L:L:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[ov];[bg][ov]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2"`

Replace `L` with a literal number or a variable, which represents the length of a side.

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm! I just replaced the `L` by a variable I can set easily for reusability's sake. Thanks again!

Comment: Could you by chance provide a simpler version with a specified (white) background color instead of burring it, too?