# Melt: How to convert vertical video with black sides, to video 16:9, with blurred background sides

Tags: video, mlt, melt-framework

I saw [many discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789367/ffmpeg-how-to-convert-vertical-video-with-black-sides-to-video-169-with-blur) on how to do this with ffmpeg, but how can I do it with melt command line?

[image]

I'm using the below command to merge video and audio and to resize any video to 1280x720 which is working great with many videos in different sizes/ratios

`/usr/bin/melt "colour:black" out=15 "input.mp4" -mix 15  -mixer luma -audio-track "sound.mp4" -profile hdv_720_30p -progress -consumer avformat:"output.mp4" vcodec="libx264" vb="5000k" acodec="aac" ab="128k" frequency=44100 deinterlace=1`

I saw this filter https://www.mltframework.org/plugins/FilterPillar_echo/ which will do exactly what I want, but it requires that I know the width/height and the position (X/Y) of the video after the resizing that is done by the above command, which I have no idea how to calculate or get

Answer (score 0):

Customize to your needs, please try the `boxblur` filter it might help

```
melt \
SomeFile.mp4 \
```

> 1. now setup your blur box & customize the size/aspect

```
-filter boxblur start=1 end=300 in=65 out=70 \
-transition \
composite in=65 out=70 a_track=0 b_track=1 \
start=0/0:100%x100%:100 \
end=-100%/0:100%x100%:100 \
-track \
-blank 65 \
```

> 2. you can feed it back to another to do additional processing in steps

```
InOut.mp4 \
-transition \
composite in=65 out=70 a_track=0 b_track=1 \
start=100%/0:100%x100%:100 \
end=0/0:100%x100%:100 \
-filter boxblur start=300 end=1 in=65 out=70 \
-consumer avformat:outFile.mp4
```